# Sticky header should have some padding bottom on job page

Tags: discussion, bug

I was just exploring the jobs, i opened a [**job**](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/114426/actively-seeking-artisanal-javascript-engineer-6connect-inc?med=clc&ref=large-sidebar-orange-looking) post which anchor tag does not aligned from bottom side. I think sticky header should have some padding bottom. I checked this post on both small (`on 667 pixel height`) and large screens (`on 979 pixel height`), same issue on both screens.

[image]